# ajax load more instead of pagination

Tags: ajax, pagination

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
global $wp_rewrite;
$wp_query->query_vars['paged'] > 1 ? $current = $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] : $current = 1;

$pagination = array(
    'base'               => add_query_arg( 'paged', '%#%' ),
    'format'             => '',
    'total'              => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'current'            => $current,
    'show_all'           => false,
    'type'               => 'list',
    'prev_next'          => true,
    'prev_text'          => '<i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-left"></i> ' . __( 'Previous', 'attire' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next', 'attire' ) . ' <i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i>',
    'screen_reader_text' => '',
);

if ( $wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() && ! is_search() ) {
    $pagination['base'] = user_trailingslashit( trailingslashit( remove_query_arg( 's', get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ) ) . 'page/%#%/', 'paged' );
}

if ( ! empty( $wp_query->query_vars['s'] ) ) {
    $pagination['add_args'] = array( 's' => get_query_var( 's' ) );
}
?>
<div class="text-center">
    <?php
    echo str_replace( '<ul class=\'page-numbers\'>',
        '<ul class="pagination pagination-centered page-numbers">',
        get_the_posts_pagination( $pagination ) );
    ?>
</div>
```

can some change it to **ajax load more style** or only **prev next** button style, please help me.

Comment: what specific of your problem? to make ajax call? or remake html view of pagination?

Comment: Either previous or next button or load more, I implemented ajax load more plugin, but having CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a plugin to implement infinite scroll here is a very popular one I have used myself which seems to work well.

https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Comment: I used this but unable to setup.

Comment: @RajkumarMaity did you set up the scroll container classes in the settings to match your code?